# Need help with Error: not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#

my method's like this:-

```
protected string myMethod()
    {

        if (something)
        {
            string img = "A";
            return img;
        }
        else
          if(something else)
           {
              string img = "B";
              return img;
            }

    }
```

When I run the code "not all code paths return a value" is displayed..why so ? the method is returning that "string img" then why this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is if the `something` is false and also `somthing else` is false.

this should be better:

```
protected string myMethod()
{
    string img = string.Empty;
    if (something)
    {
        img = "A"
    }
    else 
       if(something else)
       {
          img = "B";

        }
    return img;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Ask yourself; what happens if 'something else' is false?  What is returned then?

Answer (score 2):

If both `something` and `something else` are not true, nothing can be executed and there's no string to return.
If your `something` is just `something else`'s negation, you shouldn't have any condition after `else`.

Comment: 'mutually exclusive' doesn't entail full coverage.

Answer (score 2):

Same as the other answers, but much more compact one -

```
protected string myMethod()
{
    return (something)? "A" : ((something else)? "B" : string.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected string myMethod() 
{ 

    if (something) 
    { 
        string img = "A"; 
        return img; 
    } 
    else 
      if(something else) 
       { 
          string img = "B"; 
          return img; 
        }
reture some_String_To_Return 

}
```

Comment: that looks like an error waiting to happen... You seem to be returning a string for the first two and a boolean for the last (given something is used as a boolean earlier) or was that last something meant to be more "another thing"? And there is a typo in your return that you might as well correct if you do make an edit. :)